# Ford Expedition Rear HVAC not turning on

Tags: ford, hvac, expedition

I've turned the selection dial on but the rear HVAC unit isn’t coming on. I've checked to see if everything is connected but it's still not working

Comment: What have you done or checked?

Comment: Looked to see if everything was connected. Looked when it was dark so I’ll be looking tomorrow

Comment: Hi, what year of car and which engine do you have?

Comment: Can you see any condensation dripping from the rear of the car when the AC system is on?

Comment: 2003 5.4l v8 check all plugs and they are all connected

Comment: Nothing comes on when I turn it on

Comment: I'll repeat myself, with more detail. Turn the front AC on and after some minutes check for condensation dripping down from the rear. If it does, the system isn't equipped with a rear line LLSV or it's working as required so that the evaporator is still live with a working TXV and the issue might be with the blower. If it does not, even some time after turning AC off, the issue might be with both the blower and the TXV and/or LL solenoid valve for the rear AC evaporator. Is the rear AC system blower even working? Can you turn it on and have ambient temp air actually flow out of the rear vents?

Comment: No air is coming out of vents. Fan either doesn’t work or it works and not getting power some how. I’ve bought a motor and pulged it in and turned in on and nothing happened